# Page result returns different values than the generated SQL

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data

After upgrading to spring-data-jpa 3.0.0 a JPQL query that uses Pageable is returning less elements than expected.
I executed the generated SQL from the console and that returns the correct number of elements.
I don't see a count SQL query being generated when using spring-data-jpa 3.0.0

JPQL Query:

```
@query(value = "select fsd from FeeScheduleDrugEntity fsd "
+ "left join DrugNdcEntity ndc on fsd.drug.id = ndc.drug.id and fsd.drug.noc = true "
+ "left join FeeScheduleSourceEntity fsse on fsse.id = fsd.drugFeeScheduleSource.id "
+ "where fsd.feeSchedule.id = :feeScheduleId ")
```

Generated SQL:

```
select f1_0.fee_schedule_drug_id,
f1_0.allowable_per_billing_unit,
f1_0.fee_schedule_drug_source,
f1_0.created_at,
f1_0.created_by,
f1_0.drug_id,
f1_0.fee_schedule_item_source_id,
f1_0.fee_schedule_id,
f1_0.modified_at,
f1_0.modified_by
from core.fee_schedule_drug f1_0
join core.drug d2_0 on d2_0.drug_id = f1_0.drug_id
left join core.drug_ndc d1_0 on f1_0.drug_id = d1_0.drug_id and d2_0.is_noc = true
left join core.fee_schedule_item_source f2_0
on f2_0.fee_schedule_item_source_id = f1_0.fee_schedule_item_source_id
where f1_0.fee_schedule_id=?
order by d1_0.ndc asc
offset ? rows fetch first ? rows only
```

I am expecting the same number of results from my query

Comment: Have you checked if the query executes as expected when run with the `EntityManager` directly? If not you might be seeing another Hibernate 6 bug.

Comment: Seems to be a Hibernate issue https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-15964

Comment: Are there any null values in columns annotated with NotNull? If so, as @JensSchauder suggested EntityManager would return that entity but the Repository wouldn't.